# How to fix : 404 error while loading a pop via Ajax?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, select, haml

I'm quite new to RoR so I should miss something
I'm stuck with trying to load a popup via Ajax while clicking a button
Every time I try to reach it I got the error of the Ajax method you can see below

- I believe my synthax is right
- I obviously created a 'pbbackground' file
- I also referred to that line in my button on click action
- I tried to load a popup with the content of an already functional popup but it doesn't work
- The pop-up is loading but not displaying and I'm getting the ajax error message => I guess my "sucess" part is the issue but I can't find out why
- I used "debugger;" to spot if it tries going into the 'success' part of the JS but it seems it doesn't
- While checking my browser console I saw that the error is a 404

My JS method :

```
  function loadProgressForm(resource, id){
    $(".form_loader").show();
    if(resource == "new"){
      url = "/progress_boards/new";
      popup_name = "Make A Progress Board";
    } else if (resource == "edit"){
      url = "/progress_boards/" + id + "/edit";
      popup_name = "Add/Remove Metrics";
    } else if (resource == "pbbackground"){
      url = "/progress_boards/" + id + "/pbbackground";
      popup_name = "Add A Picture";
    }
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      success: function(response, data){
        $("#progress_board_form").html(response.html);
        $("#progress_board_form").find('.modal-title').text(popup_name);
        $(".form_loader").hide();
      },
      error: function(response, data){
        alert("Error loading project form")
        $(".form_loader").hide();
      }
    })
  }
```

Button code :

```
    %li= link_to 'Add Background', 'javascript:void(0)', onclick:"$('#create_edit_progress_board_model').appendTo('body').modal('show'); loadProgressForm('pbbackground', #{@progress_board.id});"
```

Also, here is the part corresponding to my folder in my `route.rb` file :

```
resources :progress_boards do
    collection do
      get :get_progress_data
      get :get_panel_data
      get :render_tab
    end
    member do
      get :open_or_archive
    end
  end
```

Comment: `url = "/progress_boards/new"` working???

Comment: Yes, it is working fine

Comment: Are there errors in your server console?

Comment: Yes, here it is @jvillian :
Started GET "/progress_boards/7/pbbackground" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-06-25 16:54:21 +0100
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/progress_boards/7/pbbackground"):

Comment: So, you have a routing error. Please add your `routes.rb` to your question.

Comment: @jvillian Alright, this is done

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you exactly what is wrong:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/progress_boards/7/pbbackground")
```

And, as you can see, you don't have a `pbbackground` route:

```
resources :progress_boards do
  collection do
    get :get_progress_data
    get :get_panel_data
    get :render_tab
  end
  member do
    get :open_or_archive
  end
end
```

Assuming you have a `pbbackground` action on your `ProgressBoardsController`, then do:

```
resources :progress_boards do
  collection do
    get :get_progress_data
    get :get_panel_data
    get :render_tab
  end
  member do
    get :open_or_archive
    get :pbbackground
  end
end
```

BTW and FWIW: Rails errors are not always *perfectly* helpful. But, they are often *very* helpful. In this case, you were getting a `RoutingError (No route matches)` error. Which almost certainly points to your `routes.rb`. This had nothing to do with your javascript or button code. In which case, showing your javascript and button code was not relevant.

Comment: Sure thing. Feel free to upvote and/or accept for future searchers.

Comment: That's what I did but as a new member my vote is taken in account but not displayed